# R Sum of numbers multiplied by a columns in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 500 parameters (numbers) : `a1, a2, a3, ... a500`,

And a 500 columns in a data.frame : `C1, C2, ..., C500`

How can I do the sum : `a1*C1+a2*C2+....a500*C500` in R with matrix from ?

Thanks

Comment: You have 500 variables named `a1`, `a2`, etc. or just a vector `a` of length 500?

Comment: I have 500 numbers named a1, a2, etc

Comment: @Math Are these scalars?

Comment: You used `assign`, didn't you? Now you need `mget`... And someone to teach you not to do that...

Comment: Yes a1, a2, etc are scalers

Answer (score 1):

If `v1` is the vector that holds the values of the parameters and `d1` the `data.frame`

```
v1 %*% t(d1)
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  180  202  160  183

v1[1]*d1[,1]+v1[2]*d1[,2]+v1[3]*d1[,3]+v1[4]*d1[,4]+v1[5]*d1[,5]
#[1] 180 202 160 183
```

If you have `a1`, `a2` etc as object names, you could use `mget` as commented by @flodel and if the names follow a specific pattern ie, from `a1` to `a500`

```
 lst <- mget(paste0("a", 1:5))
 v1 <- unlist(lst)
 v1
 # a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 
 # 1  2  3  4  5
```

#### data

```
  a1 <-1; a2 <- 2; a3 <-3; a4 <-4; a5 <-5;
  d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20,5*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```